# If order of group is $p^2$, where $p$ is prime, how can you deduce $G$ is isomorphic to $C_{p^2}$ or $C_p \times C_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers, abelian-groups

Given $|G|=p^2$ then how can you deduce $G\cong C_{p^2}$ or $G \cong C_p \times C_p$

I have shown that G is abelian, not sure what to do next

Comment: Look for an element of order $p^2$ (equivalently: decide if $G$ is cyclic or not).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, which states that every such group is a product of cyclic groups.

If you cannot use this, note that every element has either order $p$ or order $p^2$. If an element has order $p^2$, then we have a cyclic group of order $p^2$. Otherwise every element has order $p$. Choose two elements neither of which is a power of the other; then the subgroups generated by these elements are normal, intersect trivially, and generate the whole group (because the subgroup generated by the two elements must have order $p^2$), hence we have a direct product of two cyclic groups of order $p$.

Comment: Could you explain how more precisely how to show the second part  (the case where $o(g)=p$) I'm not sure to understand why the two chosen elements intersect trivially, and generate the whole group.

Comment: @Syl The subgroups of order $p$ are cyclic and every nonidentity element is a generator. Thus if two subgroups of order $p$ intersect nontrivially then they are the same.